# How to export from WPF Datagrid to Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: c#, wpf, google-api

For my application I want to export from WPF Datagrid to Google docs Spreadsheet. I have created Spreadsheet in Google docs. What I want now is to create new worksheet every time and delete old worksheet. I am using spreadsheet link in my website to show google docs spreadsheet. Is there any ready 3-rd party tools to do this task? Can anyone recommend solution?